# How do I route local Firebase emulator traffic through Cloud NAT Static IP while testing locally?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

**Background:**

In production, some of my Firebase cloud functions connect to an external API that requires a whitelisted IP address.

I configured the cloud functions that utilize this resource to route traffic through a Serverless VPC and exit via Cloud NAT with whitelisted static IP.

I usually specify this in the runtime configuration when deploying the function like this:

```
// imports
import { RuntimeOptions } from "firebase-functions";

const runtimeOpts: RuntimeOptions = {
    vpcConnector: "functions-connector",
    vpcConnectorEgressSettings: "ALL_TRAFFIC",
}

// Exports
module.exports = {
    some_http_function: functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).region("us-central1").https.onRequest(someHTTPFunction),
}
```

---

**Question:** How to I route local, Firebase emulator traffic through my Cloud NAT when testing locally?

Comment: Cloud NAT is private to your VPC.

Comment: I understand. I want to test locally without deploying. Is that possible?

Comment: I do not use the Firebase emulator, so I do not know if you can specify a route for its traffic. How well do you understand routing, VPNs, and forwarding traffic? When I need my traffic to go out through a VPC (the one with NAT Gateway), I either set up a VPN or use SSH port forwarding. I think the easiest method for local testing is to whitelist your home public IP address. However, home Internet's change the address often so you will be updating the whitelist every few days.

Comment: Well, I'm really asking if GCP has a built-in way to route through my NAT gateway for local testing. I am sure I can come up with a workaround using VPNs etc, but if there is an official way for this to work, it would be nice to know.

Comment: You cannot configure software to use a NAT Gateway independent of a VPN, port forwarding, etc. There is no route for the software to use to get inside your VPC. Even though I do not use Firebase emulator, that detail would be a security violation that would be exploited instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting your home public IP address is the simplest approach for local testing. However, because you will be updating the whitelist frequently if you use your home internet, the address will change frequently.

It is not possible to configure applications to use NAT Gateway without a VPN, port forwarding, or other security features. Cloud NAT is only accessible within your VPC.
The software cannot enter your VPC, since there is no way for it to do so. That would be a security breach that might be exploited immediately.